# How to copy a big soap request in Eclipse for unit-testing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm writing some unit-tests in which input is `Soap` request. My request is minimum 80 lines long, when I copy that into Eclipse for unit-test, it doesn't append `+ "` in each new line. (I'd worked in `IDEA` before and that use to nicely format it and I just have to take care of escaping double quotes). Is there a better way of doing this, than manually appending + and then enclosing each line in double-quotes.

I think using `File I/O` is too much for unit-tests.

Comment: In such cases I use an ascii text editor with macro capability.

Comment: Replace (regex) every `$` with `"` and every `^` with `"+`. Then manually edit last line.

Comment: I would argue that if the data required for your unit test is indeed that long, it'd be better to keep it nicely formatted external to your test code. If you put it in a file in the same package as your unit test, you could use [getClass().getResourceAsStream("testRequest.xml")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) and get an input stream of your test data fairly easily.

Comment: I don't see $ and ^ in my request at all

Comment: @Charlie, would you use then chained `Input Streams` to convert into String or better `Scanner` class

Comment: @Learner - it would depend on what I was doing and what I needed. Sometimes you can just use the InputStream itself, other times you need to read it as bytes or a string (and there are plenty of utilities to do so). But having large chunks of data interspersed with your code could make your tests unreadable. (on the flip side, having data separate from code sometimes means needing to open 2 files to understand test code...) It's arguably a stylistic opinion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you paste the code into a string in Eclipse you can automatically insert special characters, see `Window Preferences->Java->Editor->Typing->Escape text when pasting into a string literal`

Pasting

```
foo
bar
baz
```

into

```
String s = "";
```

gives

```
String s = "foo\n" + 
        "bar\n" + 
        "baz";
```